# appending strings to a new list under if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

After reading the file directory using this line,

```
x = glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive = True)
```

I got this output,

```
doping_center9_2.txt
doping_center9_3.txt
doping_center9_4.txt
doping_center9_5.txt
n_eff_doping_center1_1.txt
n_eff_doping_center1_2.txt
n_eff_doping_center1_3.txt
n_eff_doping_center1_4.txt
```

Now, I would like to create another list and appending the strings with a starting with `n_eff`. I tried this:

```
n_eff = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == x[i].startswith("n_eff"):
         n_eff.append(x[i])
```

Unfortunately, nothing is happening there, not even an error.

Comment: Are you sure they don't have their path associated with them? When I run [`glob.glob(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) I get `['folder1/file1.txt', 'folder2/file2.txt', ...]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `startswith` is returning boolean value (`True` or `False`). You are then checking if `x[i]` is equal to a boolean value which is always false because it contains string.

Changing the condition should help:

`if x[i].startswith("n_eff"):`

Comment: I think he may also have a problem with the strings including a full or partial path, but this is definitely the main problem.

Comment: Thats exactly i was looking for. Thanks a lot! No, the path was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the output is multiline you need to split it with `split('\n')`.

Function `"<string>".startswith(<arg>)` returns True if `<string>` starts with the parameter string `<arg>`. You can check if a string starts with the specified sub string with this function.

Using list comprehension it can be written as:

```
new_list = [x for x in output if x.startswith('\n')]
```

edited considering output a list.

Comment: [`glob.glob(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) returns a list of results, not a multiline string.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [51]: x = '''doping_center9_2.txt
    ...: doping_center9_3.txt
    ...: doping_center9_4.txt
    ...: doping_center9_5.txt
    ...: n_eff_doping_center1_1.txt
    ...: n_eff_doping_center1_2.txt
    ...: n_eff_doping_center1_3.txt
    ...: n_eff_doping_center1_4.txt
    ...: '''.splitlines()
In [52]: x
Out[52]: 
['doping_center9_2.txt',
 'doping_center9_3.txt',
```

...
     'n_eff_doping_center1_4.txt']

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
In [53]: for i in x:
    ...:     if i.startswith('n_eff'):
    ...:         print(i)
    ...:         
n_eff_doping_center1_1.txt
n_eff_doping_center1_2.txt
n_eff_doping_center1_3.txt
n_eff_doping_center1_4.txt
```